# Solve for Exponent in a summation

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

For a simple summation: 
$$
 Z =  \sum_{x=1}^X x^n
$$

Solve for n. 
I have googled unsuccessfully and I do not remember this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometric_series#Geometric_series

Comment: What do you mean 'solve for n'? There's no equation here, and the sum is ill-posed; what's the index that's being summed over?

Comment: @T.Bongers This is my first question here. Lost the rest of the question with my poor MathJax.

Comment: This is not a geometric series.

Comment: Kaizen - please look at my comments at Ross's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a nice algebraic solution, so to get an accurate answer you will need to use a numeric root finder.  To get started, you can approximate the sum with an integral.
$$\int_0^{N-1}x^n\; dx \le \sum_{n=1}^N x^n\le \int_1^N x^n\; dx\\ 
\frac {(N-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\le \sum_{n=1}^N x^n\le \frac {N^{n+1}-1}{n+1}\\$$ so you can start from $n \approx  \frac {\log Z}{\log N}-1$  If you want a little closer starting approximation, you can start with that and iterate $n_i=  \frac {\log Z-\log(n_{i-1}+1)}{\log N}-1$ to convergence.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what's going on here: the series differs from the series in the question and still that answer is accepted? Here we have the index in the exponent which makes it a partial geometric series and in the OP's question the index is in the base, having a fixed exponent making it a partial Dirichlet-series... *(Hmm, besides of that, the answer is informative anyway, at least for me because I'm generally weak with integrals and I'll think about this...;-) )*

Comment: Another one: from the truncated geometric series I get the solution $N = \log_x ( Z \cdot (x-1) / x +1) $. Did I miss something?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms:  The series sums over $x$, not $n$, so is not geometric.  We were asked to find $n$ given $Z,N$

Comment: Yes, that made my first comment. But after that "accepting" - what should we think about the question? And is the OP at all willing to react on the comments and remarks?

Comment: It seems, it is meant *"solve $\zeta(n,1)-\zeta(n,X+1)=n$ for $n$ "* (where $\zeta(s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1/(a+k)^s $ is the Hurwitz-zeta (over the real numbers only))

Comment: @GottfriedHelms:  To get the two integrals, the sum is the Riemann sum of the left one using the upper end of each interval of width $x$.  Since the function is increasing, it is an upper limit.  The right one is similar but using the lower end of each interval, so is an overestimate.

Comment: Well, I'm no more aware what's going on here, sorry, I'm stepping out.

Comment: For positive integer $X$ we have the Faulhaber formulae, no? They provide an exact algebraic expression

Comment: @FShrike:  yes, but those go in the wrong direction.  We are trying to find the right one of the formulas, or maybe an $n$ that is not an integer if that is required.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an addendum to Ross' answer, which on one hand assumes a geometric series (different from the OP's question) but on the other hand is accepted anyway. Ross' ansatz, whatever meant, can be improved*

If indeed the *geometric* series (where the index goes into the exponent of the sum-term) were intended then there is a much simpler answer:
$$ \begin{eqnarray} Z&=& \sum_{k=1}^n x^k = x{x^n-1\over x-1} \\
 Z \cdot {x-1\over x}  &=& x^n -1 \\
 Z \cdot  {x-1\over x}+1  &=& x^n \\
  n &=& \log_x \left( Z \cdot {x-1\over x}+1 \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve that which is neither a problem nor an equation :). What you likely mean ism how do i express the sum
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^N x^n
$$
in terms of $N$, its upper limit.

To do that, what would happen if you were to compute $S - S \cdot x$? Can you derive the formula for $S$ from here?

Comment: I have updated the question and commented in response to @T.Bongers

Comment: I have updated the question above